# VSCode Extension Development Host does not allow enabling extension dependencies

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, module.exports, vscode-api

I am creating a VSCode extension which requires another extension specified in the dependencies section of the package.json file. My extension will get this extension and use its functions. However, the Extension Development Host does not allow the extension to be enabled (i.e. the button for enable is greyed out, the command in command palette does not do anything.

The GitHub issue here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/71194
does not describe *how* to enable the extensions when it simply doesn't allow you to.

Here is the code in package.json, as outlined by [the official documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-manifest):

```
  "extensionDependencies": [
    "michaelcurrin.auto-commit-msg"
  ],
```

The code used in getting the extension:

```
const autofill_extension = await vscode.extensions.getExtension("michaelcurrin.auto-commit-msg")?.exports;
```

What it says in the Extension Development Host:
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDTTH.png)

Update: [I have created a GitHub issue on this.](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/171940)

Comment: That issue mentions installing missing dependencies command which must be `Extensions: Install Missing Dependencies`.  Once you are in the `Extension Development Host` trigger that command from the Command Palette and see if the `...getExtension("michaelcurrin.auto-commit-msg")?.exports;` command works.  You will have to trigger that part of the code in some way after you have run the ` Install Missing Dependencies` command - if that isn't behind one of your command's already.  If so, just for testing, register a command that you trigger in which you try to access that dependency extension.

Comment: Alternatively,  I suppose you might try `await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.extensions.installMissingDependencies');` at the start of your `activate` function, *maybe* that would work.  And then obviously, remove that when you publish the extension.

Comment: @Mark Didn't work, it just says "There are no missing dependencies to install."

Comment: I might create a GitHub issue on this.